# How fix sigar library when I run spray application?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, spray, sigar

I have a sbt project written in scala. The project uses akka and spray. There is a class with main function. When I run scala console application sometimes I get

```
[on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [DEBUG] [2014-11-07 16:48:30,336] Sigar: no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
```

I **do not change anything** run it again and it runs well. So it can be run successful or fail several times on end. How to fix this?

**UPDATED**

Also when it start normal there is a message:

```
[INFO] [11/07/2014 17:02:36.772] [on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]
[Cluster(akka://myApp)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://myApp@127.0.0.1:2551] - Metrics will be 
retreived from MBeans, and may be incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy 
add the 'sigar.jar' to the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 
'java.library.path'. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getPid()J
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigar is a native library for gathering performance stats, used by Typesafe Console atmos Scala library. If you're not interested in hooking up Typesafe Console to your application, you can simply remove all references to atmos library from sbt build script and app config files without affecting your app functionality.